# Ghidra shows wrong information about executable in Windows

Tags: windows, assembly, reverse-engineering, ghidra

I am try to use Ghidra for reverse engineering. I successfully installed Ghidra from official repository and try to open my test.exe executable. After Drag & Drop my test.exe file into the Ghidra, this program shows wrong information about test.exe. For example, Ghidra shows "Processor x86" whereas test.exe is 64 bit program.

Can anyone know reason or maybe its a normal behavior? Thanks for attention!

Comment: You should see it show up as `x86:LE:64:...` The important part is the 64.